# Vim python syntax highlighting hangs for very long lines

Tags: python, vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have this python script, in one line I have a 1000 character long string. I have syntax highlighting on, vim hangs on this line. If I change the file extension to c++ than it works. I suspect problems with syntax highlighting plugin is is causing the hang.

Can this be fixed somehow?  I'm using vim version 7.4.52

Comment: I think this is a bug report, and is not really a question. See `:help bugs`

Comment: Will report it, but for now I've asked if it can be hotfixed user-side :)

Comment: What version is this?

Comment: Its vim version 7.4.52

Comment: Sure, i've done that just now, splitting long string into sum of short strings, but i'm looking for a permanent hotfix despite how funny it may sound :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overly long lines can dramatically slow down Vim's syntax highlighting; usually, this is a fault of the syntax script, and you should inform its author (found in the `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/python.vim` script header).

Vim 7.4 includes the `:syntime` command, which greatly helps with troubleshooting and finding the problematic regular expression.

It might help to `:set synmaxcol=...` to a value lower than the default `3000`.

Comment: Thanks very much, this was the answer I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

### Vim hangs for very long lines

First decide if what's slowing you down is in your `~/.vimrc` or one of the many vim load scripts shown by the vim command `:scriptnames`.  See also `:help scriptnames`.  If this is your trouble then this command will be fast:

```
vim -u NONE hugefile.txt
```

The -u NONE says to not use any user configuration scripts.  You'll have to use process of elimination to find out if syntax highlighting, folding, plugins, or something else like disk errors, CPU throttling, memory leaks, virtual memory exhaustion, network latency or something else is hanging.  Turn stuff off start from your ~/.vimrc and disable the scripts in `:scriptnames` by putting the command `finish` at the top of the script file.

If that's not fast, next decide if very-long-lines are the problem.  If the lines that would be rendered in vim's buffer is in the viewpane and also very long, then vanilla vim will read every single character of that line off the disk, then inflicting `set wrap` upon that line to the buffer so that aggregate commands work.  Turn all that off with:

```
vim -u NONE --cmd "set nowrap" hugefile.txt
```

The `--cmd` means run this command before the buffer loads, that way vim doesn't bother reading the entire line.  If that's fast then your problem was vim is reading >10MB line for presentation to the buffer.  Don't do that, and you won't have a problem.

Other ideas are to eliminate `ft=`, `syn=`, and `syntax off` to isolate whodunnit.  I've seen Vim8 open 15GB files from a pcie nvme.m2 ssd under 5 seconds.  Also reminder to upgrade to neovim.

**Tell vim to help you identify which script is taking the most startuptime with:**

```
vi --startuptime log.out hugefile.txt
```

Then inspect log.out and look at the marked as taking the most time.

For introspection and performance measuring down to the level of vimscript functions and statements, see also `:help profiling` and http://vimcasts.org/episodes/profiling-vimscript-performance